# vuetify v-select: Styling. Get rid of the underline and customize the placeholder

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datatables, vuetify.js

```
  <v-col>
                    <v-select
                    class="custom" 
                      multiple
                      attach
                      chips
                      dense
                      :placeholder="header.text"
                      clearable
                      :items="columnValueList(header.value)"
                      v-model="filter[header.value]"
                    >[enter image description here][1]
                    </v-select>
                  </v-col>
```

[I want to get rid of that underline and only show the dropdown icon. I looks so messy, when i click on item, the underline gets filled and the design loks messy. Anything I can do ??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6Ux3.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. set the `v-select` into outlined
2. do this on style section

```css
.custom >>> fieldset {
  border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: please note: this feature works if you using vue-loader ;)

Comment: ref: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Answer (score -1):

```
.select_class_name.v-text-field>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot:before { 
     border-style: none; 
} 
.select_class_name.v-text-field>.v-input__control>.v-input__slot:after { 
     border-style: none; 
}
```

Just replace the class name with the name of the class on your v-select.